# 'Method [validateString] does not exist.' in laravel Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I want to validate my form input but it throws me this error in my **Laravel.log** file

production.ERROR: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Method [validateString] does not exist.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:2405

This is my Dog model

```
class Dog extends Eloquent {

// Add your validation rules here
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'age' => 'required|integer'
];

public static $customMessages = array(
    'required' => 'Man the Name atribute is REQUIRED. Fill it man.'
);

// Don't forget to fill this array
protected $fillable = ['name', 'age'];


public static function validate($data) {
    return Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
}
```

}

And in my DogsController here I validate my data

```
public function update($id)
{

    $dog = $this->DogRepo->find($id);

    if($dog)
    {   
        // $dog = $this->dogRepo->update(array_merge(['id' => $id], Input::all()));

        $validation = Dog::validate(Input::all());

        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return 'wrong data';
        } else {
            return 'ok data';
        }


        if($dog->save())
        {
            return Redirect::route('dogs.show', $id)->with('message', 'The dog has been updated!');
        }

        return Redirect::route('dogs.edit', $id)->withInput()->withErrors($this->dogRepo->errors());
    }

    App::abort(404);

}
```

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Laravel < 4.2**

There is no validation rule named `string`.

[Laravel 4.1 - Validation - Available Rules](http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/validation#available-validation-rules)

**In Laravel >= 4.2 there is a string rule**

*Updated to reflect newer versions of Laravel.*